# ifelse didn't work in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question about `ifelse` in `data.frame` in `R`. I checked several SO posts about it, and unfortunately none of these solutions fitted my case.

My case is, making a conditional calculation in a data frame, but it returns `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` even after I used `ifelse` function in `R`, which should work perfectly according to the SO posts I checked.

Here is my sample code:

```
library(scales)
head(temp[, 2:3])
  previous current
1        0      10
2       50      57
3       92     177
4       84     153
5       30      68
6      162     341
temp$change = ifelse(temp$previous > 0, rate(temp$previous, temp$current), temp$current)
rate = function(yest, tod){
  value = tod/yest
  if(value>1){
    return(paste("+", percent(value-1), sep = ""))
  }
  else{
    return(paste("-", percent(1-value), sep = ""))
  }
}
```

So if I run the `ifelse` one, I will get following result:

```
head(temp[, 2:4])
  previous current change
1        0      10     10
2       50      57  +NaN%
3       92     177  +NaN%
4       84     153  +NaN%
5       30      68  +NaN%
6      162     341  +NaN%
```

So my question is, how should I deal with it? I tried to assign `0` to the last column before I run `ifelse`, but it still failed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using an `if` `else` statement, not the `ifelse` function

Comment: @bouncyball ```if``` and ```else``` is for ```rate``` only..

Comment: BigD,  @bouncyball had it right.  When you call your ifelse, the first value of `temp$previous`,  i.e. `temp$previous[1]` is 0,  so the condition `temp$previous > 0` is false and your code will call the `rate` function.  It is `rate` that has the error.  In `rate` you have the bit of code `if(value>1)`   but value is a vector,  not a scalar. `if` only handles scalar logical conditions so you get your warning message.

Comment: @G5W wait a sec.. in the first case it should run ```temp$current``` not ```rate``` one. And for the second case, ```previous[2]``` is greater than 0 so it will run ```rate```, in this case ```value``` indeed is a scalar. Did I make some mistakes during simulation?

Comment: I think that you are misinterpreting the meaning of the arguments. Please look at `?ifelse`.  The first argument is the condition. The second argument is the value to assign when the condition is true. The third argument is the value to assign when the condition is false.  for the first row, the condition is false so it tries to assign the third argument which entails calling the rate function.

Comment: I'm still confused. In the last chunk, it got ```10``` in the last column, which is exactly what I expected (assign ```temp$current``` if condition did not fit),  but from the second rows, it should run ```rate```, which from the results we can see it didn't work. Please look at the line, there is still a third argument ```temp$current``` in  ```ifelse``` ...Hopefully I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following two segments, both should does what you wanted.  May be it is the second one you are looking for.

```
library(scales)
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(previous = rnorm(5), current = rnorm(5))
rate <- function(i) {
  yest <- temp$previous[i] 
  tod <- temp$current[i]
  if (yest <= 0)
    return(tod)
  value = tod/yest
 if (value>1) {
   return(paste("+", percent(value-1), sep = ""))
 } else {
   return(paste("-", percent(1-value), sep = ""))
 }
}

temp$change <- unlist(lapply(1:dim(temp)[1], rate))
```

Second:

```
ind <- which(temp$previous > 0)
temp$change <- temp$current
temp$change[ind] <- unlist(lapply(ind, 
                      function(i)  rate(temp$previous[i], temp$current[i])))
```

In the second segment, the function `rate` is same as you've coded it.

Comment: I like the second one! It worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do the same

```
# 1: load dplyr
#if needed install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

# 2: I recreate your data
your_dataframe = as_tibble(cbind(c(0,50,92,84,30,162),
                                 c(10,57,177,153,68,341))) %>% 
  rename(previous = V1, current = V2)

# 3: obtain the change using your conditions
your_dataframe %>% 
  mutate(change = ifelse(previous > 0,
                         ifelse(current/previous > 1,
                                paste0("+%", (current/previous-1)*100),
                                paste0("-%", (current/previous-1)*100)), 
                         current))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  previous current             change
     <dbl>   <dbl>              <chr>
1        0      10                 10
2       50      57               +%14
3       92     177 +%92.3913043478261
4       84     153 +%82.1428571428571
5       30      68 +%126.666666666667
6      162     341 +%110.493827160494
```

Comment: I have a really stupid question here, what does ```%>%``` mean in step 2?

Comment: there are no stupid questions !! `%>%` is the pipeline operator, something that follows the tidy data principles and makes code more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Only the first element in `value` is evaluated. So, the output of `rate` solely depend on the first row of `temp`.

Comment: Yes I get that part. So here is a follow-up question: how should I make improvement for this case?

Comment: 1. Vectorize the `rate` function.


2. The `ifelse` can not be used the way you are using, subset the `temp`, and the do the operations you need to do. 


3. From your question, it doesn't appear you got that part

Comment: When ever the `ifelse` becomes TRUE or FALSE, the whole `temp$change` is altered.

Comment: It seems like I misunderstood something.. My basic understanding at this point is stated in the comment under question. So here is another stupid question: is it the right way to interpret ```ifelse``` as I explained in my last comment? I'm so confused right now.

Comment: `library(scales)
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(previous = rnorm(5), current = rnorm(5))

rate = function(i) {
  yest <- temp$previous[i] 
  tod <- temp$current[i]
  if (yest <= 0)
    return(tod)
  
  value = tod/yest
  if(value>1){
    return(paste("+", percent(value-1), sep = ""))
  } else{
    return(paste("-", percent(1-value), sep = ""))
  }
}
temp$change <- unlist(lapply(1:dim(temp)[1], rate))`

Comment: Say we do `ifelse(cond, true_res, false_res)`. The `cond` may have 10 elements in it, then both 'res_true' and `'false_res` runs 10 times all together. 
It doesn't look at the corresponding row in `res_true` or `res_false`. I don't know how else to explain this, sorry.

Comment: Actually, I see that @G5W has explained using `ifelse` better than me.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting the advice I received from warm-hearted SO users, I vectorized some of my functions and it worked! Raise a glass to SO community!

Here is the solution:

```
temp$rate = ifelse(temp$previous > 0, ifelse(temp$current/temp$previous > 1, 
                                             temp$current/temp$previous - 1, 
                                             1 - temp$current/temp$previous), 
                   temp$current)
```

This will return `rate` with scientific notation. If "regular" notation is needed, here is an update:

```
temp$rate = format(temp$rate, scientific = F)
```